# Khinchin's Law of Large numbers proof unclarity.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, taylor-expansion, characteristic-functions, law-of-large-numbers

This is the formulation:
Let $X_n,n=1,2,...$ be independent, equally distributed random variables. $EX_k=a$(expectation) $k=1,2,...$. For this sequence of $X_n$ the law of large numbers applies: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k \to^{P}a.$$

Proof:
Let $t$ be  a real fixed number. (With $f_x(t)$ I denote the characteristic function of variable X).
So
$$f_{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}f_{X_k}(\frac{t}{n})=\text{(this equality is unclear to me }=(1+ai\frac{t}{n}+o(\frac{t}{n}))^n\to^{n\to \infty}\text{this is unclear to me also }=e^{ait}$$

This definitely has something to do with macloren's series of $e^x.$ I just can't see it clearly. I would very much appreciate if someone could do a step by step clarifications of these unclear inequalities to me.

Comment: The LLN you have stated here is the ``weak version,'' which is quite easily proved using Chebyshev's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_Chebyshev.27s_inequality
However, if you would like a proof using characteristic functions, here is one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_convergence_of_characteristic_functions

Comment: Hmmm, I see....

Comment: Here it says by Taylors expansion for complex numbers the characteristic function of any random variable, with finite mean.... applies that formula. Can you explain why this is. I know the taylor expansion for the exponential function. But I cant put this together.

Comment: $f_{X}(t) = 1 + i t a + o(t)$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.  For characteristic functions, however, we have:
$$$$

Comment: When $t\to0$, $$e^{itX}=1+itX+o(t)$$ hence, for $t$ fixed, when $n\to\infty$, $$e^{itX}=1+itX/n+o(1/n)$$ and, if the error term $o(1/n)$ is uniformly small, one can expect (and it indeed happens) that $$E(e^{itX})=E(1+itX/n+o(1/n))=1+itE(X)/n+o(1/n).$$ To go further one needs to justify the interversion of $E$ and $o$, but this is all there is to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was searching for. Very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f_{X}(t) = 1 + i t a + o(t)$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Characteristic functions, however, have these two general properties:
$$
f_{ {1 \over n} X(t)} = f_{X}(t/n) \quad \mbox{and} \quad
f_{ X(t) + Y(t) } = f_{X}(t) f_{Y}(t).
$$
(i.e., rescaling the original r.v. rescales the argument of the char. fun., and sums of r.v.'s are transformed into products of char. fun.'s).

The first equality that is unclear to you follows from these two properties.

The last conclusion (limit) you are asking about is obtained by dropping the negligible term $o(t)$ and examining the limit
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \; (1 + {1 \over n} i a t)^{n}.
$$
And it is one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Notable_special_limits

Comment: What goes before we have:....

Comment: thats what I dont get

Comment: why we have that.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, it's because, first of all, we have:
$$
f_{X}(0) = E[ e^{0}] = 1,
$$
and one can show (directly from the definition of the characteristic function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Properties) that
$$
f_{X}'(0) = {d \over dt} f_{X}(t)|_{t=0} = i E[X] = i a
$$

These two quantities give us the coefficients of the first two terms of the Taylor expansion of $f_{X}(t)$ near $t=0$:
$$
f_{X}(t) = f_{X}(0) + t f_{X}'(0) + \mbox{(2nd and higher powers of $t$)}.
$$
Better?